# Why is pretty_print not working in this snippet for profiling Rails application memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm following along in the Railer Performance book and it tells me to make following code snippet in environment.rb:

```
MemoryProfiler.report do
  # Load the Rails application.
  require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

  # Initialize the Rails application.
  Rails.application.initialize!

end.pretty_print(to_file: "test.txt")
```

Then I'm supposed to run `rails runner "puts 'hello world'"`

But when I do, I get:

```
/Users/samantha/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/pp.rb:316:in `pretty_print': undefined method `text' for {:to_file=>"test.txt"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  test
```

Is pretty_print a ruby gem that I am supposed to install?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `MemoryProfiler.report do ... end` block returns nil (which I don't know why it happens).

When report is present, it executes MemoryProfiler's `pretty_print` method on an instance of `MemoryProfiler::Results`.

When report is nil, it executes Ruby's `pretty_print` method on an instance of a `NilClass`.